# Ceiling and integer +1 option in R software

Tags: r, integer, rounding, ceil

Is there an elegant way to take either the ceiling (if the input is not an integer) or one integer larger (if the input is an integer) for each index of a vector?

Such that, for example, vector x

```
x = c(0, 4, 5.3333, 6.25)
```

becomes vector y

```
1, 5, 6, 7
```

Comment: how about `floor(x+1)`?

Answer (score 3):

this thinks about the issue in a little different way

`y <- floor(x+1)`

`> y
[1] 1 5 6 7`